# Using col with text and an image is not working

Tags: html, css, image, col

Hi i'm trying to get this kendrick image to the right of the text and i used the col-8 and col-4 classes before each but the image just remains below the text. Can someone tell me where i've gone wrong? thanks :)

[image: css code]

[image: html code]

Comment: DO NOT POST PICTURES OF CODE!  Post your actual code

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Html div like this

```
<div class="aboutimage col-4">
   <img src="kabout.jpg">
</div>
```

i.e remove the inner div and add the col-4 class name to the parent div insetead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: inline-block` in the CSS of both the divs that are `col-8` and `col-4`.

Try using `display: inline` in the CSS of both the divs that are `col-8` and `col-4`.

Also if it doesn't work then try removing `text-align: center` from the CSS and again try the display tags mentioned above.

I hope any of this will work.